# How to nest devise_invitable route to invite user to specific project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

## Problem

I'm using `devise` and `devise_invitable` gems on a project management web app. I am successfully inviting new users to to the web app.

**But what I need is to invite new users *to a specific project* and can't figure out how to do that.** I need the project ID as part of the route so I can properly wire up the controller code.

## Context

Relevant `routes.rb` section looks like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => "invitations" }
```

So:

- `users/invitation/new` works for new invitations.
- My own `invitations_controller.rb` overrides default `InvitationsController`
- I have `:projects` as a resource that I'm using, e.g.

  ```
   resources :projects do
     resources :milestones, :task ... etc
   end
  ```

(I think) I am looking to make something like this work:

```
users/invitation/projects/4f3423d34323/new
```

Answer (score 5):

Current approach is to specify the route using `devise_scope`:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => "invitations" }

devise_scope :user do 
   match "/projects/:project_id/invitations/new", :to => "invitations#new", :via => "get", :as => "new_project_invitation"
end
```

This means I can use:

Case 1: `users/invitation/new` (for inviting new user to web app)

and

Case 2: `projects/:project_id/invitations/new` (for inviting new user to web app + project)

`invitations_controller#new` checks for presence of `:project_id` and invokes appropriate behaviour for Case 1 or 2.