# How to invite a user to project with devise_invitable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm building the app, where users can be invited to a particular project/workspace/team. But by default it allows to invite users to the app, not a particular project. This question seems to be very similiar [How to nest devise_invitable route to invite user to specific project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354368/how-to-nest-devise-invitable-route-to-invite-user-to-specific-project)
Does anyone know, how to override **invitations_controller** in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `invite` action inside your `projects_controller.rb` and invite the user directly to a project.

Simply associate the invited `User` to a `Project` immediately after inviting. Here's a snippet to give you an idea of how you could approach this.

```
# POST /projects/:id/invite { name: "John Smith", email: "john@email.com" }
def invite
  # Set the current project
  @project = Project.find(param[:id])

  # Create your own strong_invite_params method to allow name and email
  invited_user = User.invite!(strong_invite_params, current_user)

  # If a simple belongs_to :project association
  invited_user.update(project: @project.id)

  # If a complex association through a separate projects_membership table
  invited_user.projects << @project
end
```

Comment: Not sure whether creating the users we invite before they even accept is a good choice